# Testing async mapDispatchToProps actions with Jest/Enzyme gives error

Tags: asynchronous, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme, redux-thunk

I am trying to test my mapDispatchToProps actions when an async function is dispatched. I almost tried every possible solution I found and nothing worked so far. I'm always getting the same error:

I'm getting this error:
TypeError: store.dispatch(...).then is not a function

I tried the solution included in redux-mock-store https://github.com/dmitry-zaets/redux-mock-store. I included my middlewares to my mockStore, but it didn't fix the issue.

I tried the solution proposed by Michael Peyper here [Testing dispatched actions in Redux thunk with Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48172819/testing-dispatched-actions-in-redux-thunk-with-jest).

We created a function to build the mockStore so I tried to create my mockStore directly within my test file instead, but they both returned the same error.

I can't put all the solutions I tried here because it would take me weeks, but it gives you an idea.

Here's the code for my test:

```
describe('Component async actions', () => {
        const middlewares = [thunk, queryMiddleware];
        const createMockStore = configureStore(middlewares);
        const store = createMockStore();

        afterEach(() => {
            jest.clearAllMocks();
        });

        const someData = {};

        const expectedActions = { 
            type: ADD_DATA,
            payload: someData
        };

        it('should handle addData', () => {
            return store.dispatch(actions.addData(someData)).then(() => {
                expect(store.getActions()[0]).toEqual(expectedAction);
            });
        });
 });
```

Here's my mapDispatchToProps:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        addData: data => dispatch(addData(data))
            .then(({ status }) => {
                dispatch(showNotification({ status }));
            }),
    };
};
```

I would like to at least be able to get to the expect part and fix this if there's any error in my test, but I can't get passed the dispatch().then

Again, here's the error I get each time: TypeError: store.dispatch(...).then is not a function

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does `actions.addData` return a `Promise`?

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors Yes it does

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors You seem to have a lot of experience with testing async dispatch with jest and enzyme. My solution works but it doesn't enter the .then part. I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this so I can also test the 'showNotification' part.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if anyone will get this problem, but I found a solution.

First of all, I had to add my thunk middleware to my createStore from redux-mock-store.

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

...

const createMockStore = createStore([thunk]);
```

Then I did a mock of my addData function like this:

```
import { addData } from 'path/to/addData';

...

jest.mock('path/to/addData');
```

and I added this code within my test:

```
addData.mockReturnValue(() =>
        new Promise((resolve) => resolve({ status: 200 }));
        ));
```

It works!